# http server with ssl does not work with nc

Tags: ssl, https, nc

If run:

```
cat index.html  | nc --ssl --broker --keep-open   -l 443
```

on the client side browser keeps on trying to connect with no success. I mean, the html page does not load.

Besides, curl output is:

```
curl -v  -k https://10.0.3.226/index.html
*   Trying 10.0.3.226:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.0.3.226 (10.0.3.226) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=localhost
*  start date: Oct 30 13:06:20 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 29 13:06:20 2020 GMT
*  issuer: CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.0.3.226
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
>
```

Is there a way to that it works?

PS: nc is ncat from nmap package.

Comment: When I try this, `curl` shows me the contents of `index.html` -- the first time; after that, it hangs because there's no more input to `nc`.  Did you remember to restart the `cat ... | nc` pipeline for each attempt?

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP/1 response requires a HTTP header (status code, meta data) and a HTTP body (i.e. the content). Your `index.html` is likely only the content. If this is an accepted response depends on your client supporting the more than 20 year obsolete HTTP/0.9 protocol (where no header is sent) or not. Many don't.

Comment: This explains why a browser might not retrieve/show the page, but Curl 7.65.3 (the version the OP specified) will show the document body even without any headers in the response.